# Subtract in moment js not exactly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have function calculate last month when send start day of month like this

`last_date_from = moment(date_from).subtract(1, 'months');
last_date_to = moment(last_date_from).endOf("month").startOf("day");`

When i send object moment start day

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: Object, _locale: Locale, _d: Tue Mar 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)…}
_d: Tue Mar 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale
_offset: 0
_pf: Object
__proto__: Moment
```

Funtion will return 2 result last_date_from and last_date_to:

```
d: Sat Jan 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale
_offset: 0
_pf: Object
__proto__: Moment
```

Last_date_to is:

```
_d: Sun Jan 31 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)
__proto__: Date
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale
_offset: 0
_pf: Object
__proto__: Moment
```

Expected result last_date_from is 1/2/2016 why result is 30/1/2016. I know this year. February have 29 days. How to fix this ? Sorry my English is not good

Comment: Is that possible because the UTC time zone?

Comment: I dont understand ! Can you explain ? Thanks